# Oracle calculations within Crystal report

Tags: oracle

I have this code in a Crystal report. It uses 2 fields, `st.pass_total` and `st.fail_total` to calculate the pass ratio. I'd like to replace this Crystal code with PL/SQL code to return just the pass_ratio:

```
if isnull({st.PASS_TOTAL}) 
   and isnull({st.FAIL_TOTAL}) then pass_ratio:=""
else if (not isnull({st.PASS_TOTAL})) 
        and isnull({st.FAIL_TOTAL}) then pass_ratio:="100%"
else if (isnull({st.PASS_TOTAL})
           or {st.PASS_TOTAL}=0) 
         and (not isnull({st.FAIL_TOTAL})) then pass_ratio:=""
else pass_ratio:=totext({st.PASS_TOTAL}/({st.PASS_TOTAL}+{st.FAIL_TOTAL})*100)+"%";
```

This is what I have in PL/SQL, is it correct?

```
decode((is_null(st.pass_total) AND is_null(st.fail_total)), "",
       (not is_null(st.pass_total) AND not is_null(st.fail_total)), "100%",
       ((is_null(st.pass_total) OR st.pass_total=0) && not is_null(st.fail_total)), "",
       (st.pass_total/(st.pass_total+st.fail_total)*100)||"%"))
```

I also have one that "calculates" the Cutoff value:

```
if {e.eve_cutoff}=0
   or isnull({e.eve_cutoff}) then event_cutoff:="140"
else if {e.eve_cutoff}>0 then event_cutoff:=totext({e.eve_cutoff},0);
```

This is what I have in PL/SQL, is it correct?

```
decode(e.eve_cutoff, 0, "140",
       e.eve_cutoff, NULL, "140",
       eve_cutoff)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `decode` statements have several issues. This syntax can be greatly simplified by using function `nvl()`:

```
select 
    case 
      when nvl(st.pass_total, 0) = 0 then ''
      else 100 * st.pass_total / (st.pass_total + nvl(st.fail_total, 0)) ||'%' 
    end ratio
  from st
```

and:

```
select decode(nvl(eve_cutoff, 0), 0, '140', eve_cutoff) cutoff from e
```

[[SQLFiddle1]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d957b/2) . [[SQLFiddle2]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd8c2/1)

For first `select` you may also want to round values with function `round()`, like I did in SQLFiddle - 
(if you do not do it you may get overflow error in report).

Comment: Perfect. I had to modify it slightly to work but thanks.